# como hacer para qeu se imprima el vector en pantalla en java

Tags: java

Buen dia
me podrian ayudar con este codigo lo realize pero nesesito que me imprima los numeros que hay en el vector en pantalla y no se como hacerlo uno independiente tipo que en uno diga primos y despliega los numeros primos pares e impares de la misma manera
estas son las especificaciones que me pidieron
En el vector Introducir números desde el 1000 hasta 9000
De un vector a otro introducir pares
impares
primos
imprimir vectores resultante
mostrar cantidad de pares,impares,primos
//************************************************************************************************

adjunto el codigo
package vector_pares_impares_primos;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class classs {

```
//matriz N X M de pares e impares 
    public static void main(String[]args) {
         Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
         int num, n,m=0, par=0, impar=0, nprim=0, n1=0;
         int j, d;

        System.out.println("cuantos numeros desea ingresar en el primer arreglo:");
        n=lector.nextInt();
        int M[]=new int[n];
        int M1[]=new int[n]; // par
        int M2[]=new int[n];
        int M3[]=new int[n];  // primo
        
        System.out.println("cuantos numeros desea ingresar en el segundo arreglo:");
      n1=lector.nextInt();
      int N[]=new int[n1];
      
      
      for (int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("ingrese un numero:");
      num=lector.nextInt();
      // el numero debe estar entre 1000 y 9000 
         while (num<1000 || num>9000) {
         System.out.println(num+" numero incorrecto [1000,9000] ");
             System.out.println("ingrese un numero en el rango :");
             num=lector.nextInt();
         }

         M[i]=num;
      }
      for (int i=0; i<M.length;i++) {
          if(M[i]%2==0) {  
                          M1[par] = M[i];
              par=par+1;
          }else {
                         M2[impar] = M[i];
              impar=impar+1;
          }
                  // ver si es primo 
            j = 1;
            d = 0;
            while (j<= M[i] && d<=2) {
                 
                if (M[i]%j==0) {
                    d = d+1;
                }
                j = j+1;
            }
            if (d==2) {
                M3[nprim] = M[i];
                nprim = nprim+1;
            }

      }
      System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Total de numeros pares: "+par);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Total de numeros impares: "+impar);
        System.out.println("Total de numeros primos: "+nprim);
      System.out.println("=============================");

    
    }
      
}
```

Comment: es lo mismo que para llenarlo.. haces un for, y vas mostrando posicion por posicion...

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu código, todos los array que tienes son del mismo tamaño.

El código para la parte que imprime en pantalla tendría un aspecto similar a este.

```
System.out.println("--");
    System.out.println("Total de numeros pares: "+par);
    for(int x=0;x<par;x++) {
        if(M1[x]!=0)
            {System.out.print(M1[x]+" ");}
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Total de numeros impares: "+impar);
    for(int y=0;y<impar;y++) {
        if(M2[y]!=0) 
        {System.out.print(M2[y]+" ");}
    }
    System.out.println(""); 
    
    System.out.println("Total de numeros primos: "+nprim);
    for(int z=0;z<nprim;z++) {
        if(M3[z]!=0) {
            System.out.print(M3[z]+" ");}
        }
  System.out.println("");       
  System.out.println("=============================");
```

Por lo que he visto vas rellenando los arrays dependiendo de número, los espacios que sobran -Java te los rellena con 0 para que no tengas nulos-. Esto lo tienes que comprobar porque el último elemento te mostraría 0 como numero. Al indice no le puedes restar 1 porque en caso de no haya un tipo de número el indice se iría a -1 y ya sería tratar excepciones.

Espero haberte ayudado.